# why my union index not working in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql

I create a union index in my table like this:

```
CREATE INDEX app_list_idx ON report_envelope_app_list (created_time,round_id,app_id);
```

this is the created result:

[image]

then I using this to see, but not using the index:

```
explain select *
from report_envelope_app_list
where created_time > 1598716800000
and created_time < 1599716800000
```

this is the explain result:

[image]

why the index not working? what should I do to fix it? created a single `created_time` index? the a,b,c index will work with the left match rule a.This is my table DML:

```
CREATE TABLE `report_envelope_app_list` (
  `id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '主键',
  `send_time` bigint(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '发包时间',
  `sender` bigint(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '发包人',
  `sender_name` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '发包人姓名',
  `code` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '房间编号',
  `room_type` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '房间公私类型',
  `house_type` bigint(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '房间创建类型',
  `room_type_name` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '房间公私类型名称',
  `house_type_name` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT '' COMMENT '房间类型',
  `room_amount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '普通房间数',
  `room_id` bigint(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '房间类型ID（与house_type一致）',
  `room_play_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `room_play_name` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '是否删除',
  `wallet_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT '红包ID',
  `created_time` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT '创建时间',
  `updated_time` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT '更新时间',
  `room_amount_range` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '房间金额范围',
  `round_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '局ID',
  `app_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT '应用ID',
  `app_mark` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '应用标记',
  `room_amount_fmt` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '房间金额格式化',
  `tenant_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT '租户ID',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `app_list_idx` (`created_time`,`round_id`,`app_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=705829 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin COMMENT='游戏记录';
```

Comment: Why you decide that it should it be used? How many rows does your query returns? Does the index by `created_time` is used in the same query? Does the statistic is actual? execute ANALYSE TABLE before.

Answer (score 1):

If more than about 20% of the table is being extracted, the index is a waste of time.  To see this, try a smaller range.

The explain 585K of 705K rows will be extracted.  The bouncing back and forth between the index's BTree and the data's BTree is not worth the effort.  It is much faster to simply scan the data, ignoring rows that don't match.

(Your Question is a common one.  My Answer is always about the same.)